# assigning values to an integer array within a Fortran module

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have a module in Fortran called QFoo. It defines a type QFooType.

I want to initialize all the elements of integer array 'is_n' to 0 and want to do it within the module. Could someone help? Thank you!

```
  module QFoo
      type QFooType              
          integer::i              
          integer, dimension(50) :: is_n                         
      end type QFooType

     !-----------
     ! I know the following code is wrong
     ! but I want to initialize all the is_n elements to 0
     !-----------
     ! do i = 1, 50
     !    is_n(i) = 0
     ! enddo
     !-----------
  end module QFoo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
integer, dimension(50) :: is_n = 0
```

works on the latest version of the Intel Fortran compiler.  My reading of the Fortran 95 standard suggests that this is standard behaviour.

Comment: great! it worked.. thanks! I didn't think that the syntax we use for non array assignment will work here! Thanks again